# Taking the initiative and updating to Marshmallow without rooting. Can I do it?

Tags: updates, 6.0-marshmallow

I have an Alcatel One Touch Idol 3 running through Cricket as a carrier in the United States. It is currently on an Alcatel version of Lollipop that is reversible. My OS also frequently crashes hard and reboots.

I'm coming from using Motorola devices that were close to stock Android, and I want to go back to pure android and get the latest. Can I put Marshmallow on my phone without rooting? I'm technically able, and I could root my phone if I wanted to. I've done it many times before. I just want to put the latest Android on my phone.

Can I do it? If not, why not?

Comment: You need a custom recovery installed in the device to flash custom ROMs. If your device allows flashing from bootloader or at some low-level (such as what SP Flash Tools do with MTK devices) then you can get away without rooting the current ROM. Otherwise, I see no way to flash the custom recovery without first rooting the device.

Answer (score -1):

Without root,you can update to Marshmallow if the update is provided by your mobile manufacturer. Without root you cannot switch to custom roms.You can downgrade in few cases if that is available and provided by manufacturer.

Comment: This is not helpful. OP wants to use pure Android (vanilla build) which won't come from manufacturer. "*Without root you cannot switch to custom roms.*" -- why?